# Error: Cannot find module 'chai.as.promised'

Tags: ethereum

I do see it  in my dependencies,also I event run: npm i chai chai.as.promised again, but still cannot see the modele. Thank you for helping.

After: truffle test

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./src/contracts/Token.sol
> Artifacts written to /var/folders/1v/9ln82rd97dqghgyk_7krrwtr0000gn/T/test--22208-ZPVpGBs8ds6D
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang

Error: Cannot find module 'chai.as.promised'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/davell/my-blockchain-site/test/Token.test.js:9:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at loader (/Users/davell/my-blockchain-site/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/davell/my-blockchain-site/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:390:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles
```

I ran: npm i chai chai.as.promised

```
 my-blockchain-site git:(master) ✗ npm i chai chai-as-promised
npm WARN @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.15.4 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.13.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-proposal-class-static-block@7.15.4 requires a peer of @babel/core@^7.12.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.2 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.5.2 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN postcss-browser-comments@3.0.0 requires a peer of browserslist@^4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-apexcharts@1.3.7 requires a peer of apexcharts@^3.18.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-scripts@3.4.3 requires a peer of typescript@^3.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@8.0.2 requires a peer of node-sass@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@8.0.2 requires a peer of sass@^1.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@8.0.2 requires a peer of fibers@>= 3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ chai-as-promised@7.1.1
+ chai@4.3.4
updated 2 packages and audited 2401 packages in 11.389s
found 119 vulnerabilities (9 low, 49 moderate, 60 high, 1 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
➜  my-blockchain-site git:(master) ✗
```

But still cannot find it
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue until I discovered that in the test script I misspelt it as:
require("chai-as-promise") instead of require("chai-as-promise**d**").

Check your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I hard the same issue but I install this **npm install chai-as-promised**  from [chai-as-promised](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised)